# Drupal 7 and using custom templates with theme()

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a list of items in the default main-menu. I am trying to override the template so I may iterate over each item and custom template/theme the entire menu.

```
echo theme('links', array('links' => menu_navigation_links('main-menu', 0)));
```

main-menu is the default menu ID drupal provides. The first param to theme is telling it to use the default "links" template - this much I understand. How do I tell it to use MY mainmenu.tpl.php that resides in mytheme directory?

I have tried creating a file named `mainmenu.tpl.php` and calling it with

```
theme('links__mainmenu.tpl.php')
```

So as to provide a fallback to default links in case `mainmenu.tpl.php` should every disappear. I am naming the files wrong or something and I cannot for the life of me figure it out. Help :)

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 4):

A module's default theme is defined in the [`hook_theme`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) method. This function allows you to declare theme files (`.tpl.php`) and the variables passed to them. To declare the default theme file, use the `template` field.

```
function hook_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'mymodule_display' => array(        /* displayable name */
      'template' => 'mymodule_display', /* template file, leave off .tpl.php */
      'variable' => array(...),         /* associative array of vars used */
    )
  );
}
```

This [link](http://www.nicklewis.org/drupal-hackers-cookbook/theming/hook_theme-and-template-files) contains a more in depth example.

To invoke the module's default theme, use the [`theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/7) method, as shown in your original post. Something like:

```
<?php echo theme('mymodule_display', array(/* vars */));
```

The double-underscore is used for defining fallback themes, with the last one being preferred. Therefore, `theme('links__mymodule_display', ...)` means that Drupal will use the `Links` module theme only if `mymodule_display` cannot be resovled.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of basic but does your theme implement the base theme and is your theme set to the default?